# search component/plugin in joomla

Tags: plugin, search, plugin-events, com-search

I am new to joomla! and would like to design a custom search plugin to search through my database. I know that when using the default search, the `onContentSearch()` function is triggered and "search keywords" will be sent to the above function rather than all of input string in search field. For example, if we want to search the term `This is a book`, then two keywords: `This` and `book` will be sent to `onContentSearch()`. In my customize search plugin, I want to send all of words (i.e. `This`, `is`, `a`, `book`) in term `This is a book` to `onContentSearch()`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override/Change the return values of the `getIgnoredSearchWords()` and `getLowerLimitSearchWord()` in `/language/en-GB/en-GB.localise.php` (and any other `/language/<lang>/<lang>.localise.php` file of active languages).