# How to adjust search keyword sanitization settings as language override?

Tags: plugin, overrides, language, com-search

I am working on some custom search plugins and I have a 2-part question regarding the file `administrator/components/com_search/helpers/search.php`.

I want to adjust the sanitization settings without hacking core files.

I need `$lower_limit = 1;`
The core script supplies a value of `3` and reads:

```
$lower_limit = $lang->getLowerLimitSearchWord();
```

I have found the reference https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Language.Language.html#method_getLowerLimitSearchWord.
It tells me:

> ***integer*** The lower limit integer for length of search words (3 if no value was set for a specific language)

but this doesn't tell me how/where to override that default value.  I assume I should be doing something like `COM_SEARCH_LOWER_LIMIT_SEARCH_WORD=1` or something.

**Question 1.** Which language override file do I need to write to and what is the appropriate syntax?

The next setting to understand is `$search_ignore = $lang->getIgnoredSearchWords();`.  Right now, it is showing me a whitelist of `and`, `or`, and `in`.

**Question 2.** How do I adjust the `getIgnoredSearchWords()` strings?

I found where the default values are stored, but I don't want to hack this file:
https://github.com/joomla-framework/language/blob/master/Tests/data/language/en-GB/en-GB.localise.php

[This JSE question is virtually a duplicate](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/22155/12352) but it fails to explain how to override these defaults.

I'm not meant to touch `/language/en-GB/en-GB.localise.php`, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look for methods called `set<PROPERTY>Callback` on the same API documentation you linked. E.g. to override the lower limit use `Joomla\CMS\Language\Language::setLowerLimitSearchWordCallback()`.

> I'm not meant to touch /language/en-GB/en-GB.localise.php, right?

Correct. This should be done in a system plugin:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin;

class PlgSystemExample extends CMSPlugin
{
    protected $app;

    public function onAfterInitialise()
    {
        $this->app->getLanguage()->setLowerLimitSearchWordCallback(array(__CLASS__, 'setLowerLimitSearchWord'));    
    }

    public static function setLowerLimitSearchWord()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

You can pass an anonymous function too:

```
$this->app->getLanguage()->setLowerLimitSearchWordCallback(
    function()
    {
        return 2;
    }
);
```

For setting ignored search words use `setIgnoredSearchWordsCallback()`:

```
public function onAfterRoute()
{
    $this->app->getLanguage()->setIgnoredSearchWordsCallback(array(__CLASS__, 'setIgnoredSearchWords'));
}

public static function setIgnoredSearchWords()
{
    return ['in', 'and', 'or', 'if'];
}
```

Regarding plugin events, you can use either `onAfterInitialise()` or `onAfterRoute()`. Anything later will not work. Use `onAfterRoute()` if you need the use of input variables, e.g. to limit the plugin to specific pages.

Comment: I checked that again and the property is indeed protected and the setter method use is appropriate, so your answer is good and useful.

Comment: @Sharky We were able to quickly and simply implement your advice in a new System Plugin.  Thank you.  Out of curiosity, can this be performed inside of a Search Plugin? or does it need to be done in a System Plugin? I have a few small custom Search Plugins that I wish to apply these changes to.

Comment: @mickmackusa Apparently, yes, this can be done using `onContentSearchAreas` event.

Comment: My boss and I are wondering what country you are operating out of.  I don't know you beyond your username.

Comment: @Sharky Can you provide a full example for such a `onContentSearchAreas` event? I have such a function in a JPlugin, so what should I add there to eliminate all stop words, for example? This would help newcomers like me.

Comment: @Sven The code is already posted above. You may use a different event. I would not use `onContentSearchAreas` though. The code sets the properties of the global language object and doing this too late could lead to weird behavior with some places using old values and others using new values.

Comment: @Sharky Thanks. I had the `protected $app;` in the wrong position. After experimenting, your code works for me. Thanks!