# How to avoid downcasing of search words?

Tags: joomla-3.x, search, com-search

Relevance of case information differs from language to language. In English, it might be low, but consider cases like "who" vs "WHO" and "us" vs "US". In German, it is much higher because nouns are capitalized. `com_search` downcases all search words. I have been looking for an option that enables case-sensitive search (similar to options mentioned in question [How to adjust search keyword sanitization settings as language override?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/24255)), but could not find any.

Comment: Are you looking to have case sensitive search?

Comment: Yes, I tried to improve the question according to your question. But preserving the casing for the query would be enough for me, because I am using a search plugin that is already case-sensitive for retrieving search hits.